# Read vpn configuration from file in android like iPhone

Tags: android, vpn

In iPhone I can download VPN network configuration and when I open it, it will directly open the setting screen and configure it with data from file. can I do the same behavior in android 
??

Please if anyone can help.

Comment: You can configure certificates in Settings > Security > Credential Storage > Install from storage > select your file

Comment: btw, this is a Q&A website related to software development, this question is not related to that..

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a developer and I really need help in this, do you know how to be able to get certificate file for my vpn connection ? and If it is possible to read this certificate file by code

Comment: It wasn't very clear from your question, also your comment should instead be the question ;) yes you can do that, you should package the certificate with your application (assets folder). You can read that file like any other file from the assets

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but do you know how to package the certificate ??

Comment: yes, place it in the assets folder, then it will be packaged within your apk

Comment: No I mean how to generate this certificate file, now I have IP, username and password, how to generate the certificate file with these information ?

Comment: Normally a Central Authority (CA) will generate certificates. This is an entity that is considered to be a trusted third party. It is also possible to generate a self signed certificate, but hence it is not generated by a trusted party. it will not be seen as trusted by others. I personally don't much experience related to self signed certificates. I advice you to do some more reading related to the topic.